# Timer Issue on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, timer, countdowntimer

I am having a problem with the Timer in my quiz Game. Essentially it's a multiple choice game and the player is timed on each question. I have the timer starting when the application starts and the player sees the first question. My issue is that if the player answers the question correctly or Incorrectly the timers starts giving random values, even though I reset the timer to 30 seconds on the onclick method. How do I get the timer to start at 30 seconds and countdown normally.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Views
    TextView questionTextView;
    TextView mscoreTextView;
    TextView mtimerTextView;
    Button mchoice1;
    Button mchoice2;
    Button mchoice3;
    Button mchoice4;


    //Constructors
    private questions Question = new questions();
    private Answers cAnswers = new Answers();
    private choices Choices = new choices();

    //Variables
    private int questionNumber = 0;
    private int mScore = 0;
    private String correctAnswer;


    public void onClick(View view) {

        Button answer1 = (Button) view;

        if(answer1.getText() == correctAnswer) {

            mScore = mScore + 1;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CORRECT!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mtimerTextView.setText("30s");
            runTimer();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WRONG!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mtimerTextView.setText("30s");
            runTimer();

        }

        updateScore(mScore);
        updateUI();
    }


    private void updateScore(int points) {

        mscoreTextView.setText("" + points + "/" + Question.getLength());
    }


    public void runTimer() {

        new CountDownTimer(30100, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                String tick = String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished/1000 + "s");
                mtimerTextView.setText(tick);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TIME RAN OUT!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mtimerTextView.setText("0s");
                updateUI();
            }
        }.start();


    }


    private void updateUI () {

        if (questionNumber < Question.getLength()) {
            questionTextView.setText(Question.getQuestion(questionNumber));
            mchoice1.setText(Choices.getChoices(questionNumber, 1));
            mchoice2.setText(Choices.getChoices(questionNumber, 2));
            mchoice3.setText(Choices.getChoices(questionNumber, 3));
            mchoice4.setText(Choices.getChoices(questionNumber, 4));
            correctAnswer = cAnswers.getAnswer(questionNumber);

            questionNumber ++;

        } else {


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is the last question", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HighScoreActivity.class);
            //intent.putExtra("Score", mScore);
            //startActivity(intent);


        }

        runTimer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        questionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionTextView);
        mchoice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
        mchoice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
        mchoice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice3);
        mchoice4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice4);


        mtimerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);
        mscoreTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreTextView);

        updateScore(mScore);
        updateUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: You set the `TextView`, not the timer...

Comment: Use `equals()` method instead of `==` for checking equality of strings

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, you never really **cancel** a timer you've launched. Along with this, for every time you need a timer - you create a new one, which is not essential. The following must solve your problem:

You need to store CountDownTimer in a class field:

```
private CountDownTimer timer;
```

Then you can create it once on the start of app:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    timer = createTimer();
    ...
}
```

CreateTimer function:

```
public void createTimer() {
    timer = new CountDownTimer(30100, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            ...
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            ...
        }
}
```

}

So when you need to run timer you just call:

```
timer.start();
```

And when user gives an answer, you need to cancel timer first, then start it again:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    ...
    timer.cancel();
    timer.start();
    ...
}
```

Also: you have some duplicated code in your `OnClick()` method. Regardless of user's answer correctness you need to run timer and set a value to `mtimerTextView`, so basically you want to do it outside of `if-else` construction.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a variable inside a CountDownTimer class.

```
public void runTimer() {

        new CountDownTimer(30100, 1000) {
        private int time = 30;

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mtimerTextView.setText(time--+"s");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TIME RAN OUT!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mtimerTextView.setText("0s");
                updateUI();
            }
        }.start();


    }
```

**Cancelable Timer**

If you want your Timer cancelable you have to define it as a global variable.

```
private CountDownTimer timer; // global variable
```

start the timer by calling the below runTimer() method.

```
public void runTimer() {

   timer = new CountDownTimer(30100, 1000) {
        private int time = 30;

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mtimerTextView.setText(time--+"s");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TIME RAN OUT!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mtimerTextView.setText("0s");
                updateUI();
            }
        }.start();


    }
```

You can cancel the timer by calling the below method.

```
public void stopTimer(){
   if(timer != null){
    timer.cancel();
  }
}
```

Hope this will help